# How to avoid 304 not modified in rails4, ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a beginner in rails and making a simple application with it. But every time I refresh or reload a page, it returns 304 not modified status, and ajax doesn't work at all! It really bothers a lot. I have set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false`
and added `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});`
and even`Cache-Control:no-cache`
to the application.js.
It just can't work.
Is there any effective way to make ajax working?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Turbolinks from your project. You need to do couple of steps:

- remove `turbolinks` gem from Gemfile
- remove requires from application.js and application.css
- remove data-turbolinks-track from you application layout file